# Convert rpm to deb without alien?

Tags: ubuntu, rpm, deb

How to convert rpm to deb without using alien? I am not able to install alien in my ubuntu 19?

It gives an error on packages not able to find?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use these commands as below to convert rpm to deb package.

```
sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev rubygems build-essential
sudo gem install --no-document fpm         
sudo fpm -s rpm -t deb rpmFileName.rpm
```

If you want to convert deb to rpm then simply change last command as follows:

```
sudo fpm -s deb -t rpm debFileName.deb
```

You can follow this **[fpm](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)** package link for more details.