# Debian - errors when converting Oracle SQL .rpm package to .deb using alien

Tags: debian, oracle-sqldeveloper, alien

I want to install Oracle SQL Developer on Debian.
Oracle doesn't provide a .deb installation package, only a .rpm installer.
So I'm trying to use alien to convert the .rpm package to .deb

Some details on my environment...

I'm running Debian in the Linux container of Chrome OS (Crostini) on a Snapdragon 7C equipped Chromebook

```
uname -a -> Linux penguin 5.10.101-14958-ge846e44211d8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Mar 27 19:06:58 PDT 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

cat /etc/debian_version -> 11.3

alien version 8.95.4

RPM version 4.16.1.2
```

I download the .rpm package (sqldeveloper-21.4.3-063.0100.noarch.rpm) from here [here](https://www.orac)

and run `sudo alien --to-deb sqldeveloper-21.4.3-063.0100.noarch.rpm`

I get about 20 warnings of...

```
warning: RPM v3 packages are deprecated: sqldeveloper-21.4.3-063.0100.noarch
```

And then it errors out with...

```
Package build failed. Here's the log:
dh binary
   dh_update_autotools_config
   dh_autoreconf
   create-stamp debian/debhelper-build-stamp
   dh_testroot
   dh_prep
   debian/rules override_dh_auto_install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/wynnemike/SQLDev/sqldeveloper-21.4.3'
mkdir -p debian/sqldeveloper
# Copy the packages's files.
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -not -name debian -print0 | \
        sed -e s#'./'##g | \
        xargs -0 -r -i cp -a ./{} debian/sqldeveloper/{}
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/wynnemike/SQLDev/sqldeveloper-21.4.3'
   dh_installdocs
   dh_installchangelogs
   dh_perl
   dh_usrlocal
dh_usrlocal: error: debian/sqldeveloper/usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper is not a directory
make: *** [debian/rules:7: binary] Error 25
```

I've tried using fpm as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932118/convert-rpm-to-deb-without-alien) that actually creates a .deb file but when trying to install that it errors out with...

```
dpkg: error processing archive sqldeveloper_21.4.3-063.0100_all.deb (--install):
 parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 7 package 'sqldeveloper':
 'Depends' field, invalid package name '/bin/sh': must start with an alphanumeric character
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sqldeveloper_21.4.3-063.0100_all.deb
```

Any advice gratefully received...

Thanks!

Comment: Why not download the "other platforms" option from the SQL Developer downloads page (which is a zip file you can unpack) and then install a Java JRE and run SQL Developer from that rather than trying to massage an RPM into a format it doesn't want to go into?

Comment: So I download 'sqldeveloper-21.4.3.063.0100-no-jre' and unzip it, this gives a folder called 'sqldevelop' with a bunch of folders therein and sqldeveloper.exe. I have java installed openjdk 11.0.14 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.14+9-post-Debian-1deb11u1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.14+9-post-Debian-1deb11u1, mixed mode)' - how to proceed? :)

Comment: Follow the [install instructions](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html#sqldev-install-linux): ensure you have a Java JDK installed; unpack the archive; `cd sqldeveloper`; run `./sqldeveloper.sh`; enter the location of the Java JDK; then SQL Developer should run.

Comment: Oh FFS! :) running the ./sqldeveloper.sh script did it !!! Thank you, thank you, thank you!